# How to understand AWS VPC Flow Log ports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am trying to use AWS VPC Flow Logs to find usage of ports on EC2 instances but cannot make sense of it.

For example these two rows, 10.200.10.30 is the private IP of interface. Security group allows port 443. But as shown here, destination port 33788 is ACCEPT?!

```
2 123456789123 eni-abc123ab 54.152.158.21 10.200.10.30 443 33788 6 12 6861 1550793782 1550793842 ACCEPT OK
2 123456789123 eni-abc123ab 10.200.10.30 54.152.158.21 33788 443 6 13 2745 1550793782 1550793842 ACCEPT OK
```

Okay, maybe it's just backwards then but that does not work either because other times source/destination ports are as expected...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-monitoring.html mentions two entries per connection, but instance above is not a load balancer...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your network, it appears that this is an *outbound* connection from one EC2 instance to another.

The *second* line represents the HTTPS request from the source (10.200.10.30:33788) to the destination (54.152.158.21:443), while the first line represents the packages returned for that request.

So, what host on your network has 54.152.158.21? My guess is that it's an ALB.

Comment: That IP is more likely to be an external server this instance is contacting, perhaps an external API or maybe the machine checking for OS updates.  A public IP associated with a device inside *this* VPC should not appear in the flow logs, since that mapping occurs on the other side of the Internet Gateway, and ALB-to-instance traffic would show private IPs on both sides.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - a public-facing ALB resolves as a public IP to machines inside the VPC, not as an internal IP (believe me, that has caused me no end of pain). While the request could be to any public IP, the fact that it's an EC2 address and the OP didn't mention connecting to some other machine makes me agree that it's likely to be an ALB.

Comment: I actually created an example of this, but will have to post it later -- guests have arrived.

Comment: @kdgregory agreed, it certainly could be an *outbound* connection from an instance to an ALB, even an ALB in the same VPC.  I may have misinterpreted this answer as suggesting it could be an *inbound* connection from an ALB to an instance, which is what I was arguing would involve two private addresses.  Re-reading the answer, I seem to have been disagreeing with an assertion that wasn't actually being made. I think we are all in agreement that this is an outbound connection from the instance to whatever that public IP address is, the connection being initiated by the instance.

Comment: Yeah so there is no way to know if a row in the flow log is from a response or request right? For ports 33788 and 443 you can do the obvious guess of course...

Comment: You can generally assume that if the source port is > 32768 or the destination port is < 1024 (or a "well-known" non-privileged port such as 8080) that the source is the requester. But why is that important? What are you trying to accomplish?